# sympy function gets stuck for solving nonlinear equation system

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, sympy

I am trying to find the solutions of these equation system in google colab. I have allowed my program to run for over 6 hours and nothing. I don't know what can be wrong.

Python code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import sqrt

init_printing(pretty_print=True)

var('x y z w')
var('a b1 s b2 o1 o2 c ', positive=True)


f=x*(1-x)-(y+z)
g=a*x*y-y*w-b1*y
h=s*x*z-z*w-b2*z
j=o1*y*w+o2*z*w-c*w


solve([f, g, h, j], (x, y, z, w)) #Also try with nonlinsolve and is the same issue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `manual=True` flag. It gives 7 solutions in about a second or so.

```
>>> solve([f, g, h, j], (x, y, z, w), manual=True)
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
(1, 0, 0, 0),
(b1/a, b1*(a - b1)/a**2, 0, 0),
(b2/s, 0, b2*(-b2 + s)/s**2, 0),
((b1 - b2)/(a - s),
  (c*(a - s)**2*(o1 - o2) + o2*(-a*b1*o1 + a*b2*o1 + b1**2*o1 - 2*b1*b2*o1 +
   b1*o1*s + b2**2*o1 - b2*o1*s + c*(a - s)**2))/(o1*(a - s)**2*(o1 - o2)),
  (a*b1*o1 - a*b2*o1 - b1**2*o1 + 2*b1*b2*o1 - b1*o1*s - b2**2*o1 + b2*o1*s -
   c*(a - s)**2)/((a - s)**2*(o1 - o2)), 
  (a*b2 - b1*s)/(-a + s)),
(1/2 - sqrt(-4*c + o2)/(2*sqrt(o2)), 0, c/o2,
  -b2 + s/2 - s*sqrt(-4*c + o2)/(2*sqrt(o2))),
(1/2 + sqrt(-4*c + o2)/(2*sqrt(o2)), 0, c/o2,
  -b2 + s/2 + s*sqrt(-4*c + o2)/(2*sqrt(o2)))]
```